# How to make sure the subquery in WHERE is evaluated first?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which performs a few JOINs and has a WHERE clause that contains a subquery:

```
            WHERE
              S.warehouse_id IN (
                SELECT
                  id
                FROM a_warehouses
                WHERE
                  account_id = ...
                  AND id NOT IN (...)
              )
```

The subquery *might* very well return 0 values, in which case the outer query would return 0 values. EXPLAIN shows that mysql begins executing other (costly) joins first and applies WHERE, hence the subquery, last whereas I would want it to evaluate the subquery first because, if it returns 0, it would avoid those costly joins. I am on mysql 5.7 and, I believe, prior to mysql 8.0.18 which implements EXPLAIN ANALYZE I have no way of verifying if the actual execution plan is the same as EXPLAIN's estimate.

Therefore, I am adding a further EXISTS() clause to the WHERE which contains the same subquery, in which case I can see that EXPLAIN shows "Impossible WHERE" and skips the costly joins because the subquery is indeed evaluated first.

Is there a way for me to know if the IN(subquery) is evaluated first in contrast to what EXPLAIN says?

Comment: *The subquery might very well return 0 values* It may return 0 records due to conditions and data, or it is evaluated into inconistent expression which cannot return records? PS. Anycase the subquery is executed when execution plan is already built.

Comment: The subquery might or might not return rows, depending on different conditions. Not sure I understand what you mean by 'the subquery is executed when execution plan is already built'.

Comment: *Not sure I understand what you mean by 'the subquery is executed when execution plan is already built'.* First step - plan builds. Second step - plan executes. If the fact that the subquery will return 0 records IS NOT ESTABLISHED on the step 1 - the subquery WILL BE EXECUTED on the step 2.

Comment: Uhm, alright. So if I wrap the subquery within EXISTS(..subquery..) it is evaluated in the 'building' phase whereas if I wrap it within IN(..subquery..) it is evaluated in the 'execution' phase. My predicament is, can I somehow keep the IN(..) version and have the subquery evaluated before everything else (i.e. the costly joins)?

Comment: The point is that EXISTS() is treated as a subquery and evaluated before the outer query, hence EXPLAIN sees right away that it will return zero records whereas the IN() version is probably rewritten as a JOIN (and execution begins from there indeed). I think the two version are equivalent in the sense that further joins are never executed.